# Weird behavior when using ngrx effect with withLatestFrom operator

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, rxjs, ngrx

I have below selector

```
export const selectUserData = createSelector(selectState, state => {
    return state.user;
});
```

And in my effect, if I'm using `withLatestFrom` without []

```
withLatestFrom(
     this.commonStore.pipe(select(selectUserData))
)

loadUser$ = createEffect(() =>
        this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType(UserActionsTypes.GetUserSuccess),
            withLatestFrom(
                this.commonStore.pipe(select(selectUserData))
            ),
            mergeMap(([_, user]) => { 
                  console.log(user);

}
```

The console.log will return null data

But If I add [] to withLatestFrom

```
withLatestFrom(
     [this.commonStore.pipe(select(selectUserData))]
)
```

Then I will get data using subscribe in mergeMap

```
console.log(user.subscribe(x => console.log(x)));
```

Please note that the selector is having data and I check in redux devtool the data exist.

Any idea of how it happened?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use withLatestFrom with a selector in ngrx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60282687/how-to-use-withlatestfrom-with-a-selector-in-ngrx)

Comment: @AndrewAllen thank you I tried it but it does not work for my case

Comment: everything is looking okay. try to debug `return state.user` to see what it returns - may be `null` is the right cause of your flow in other parts of an app that we cannot see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem must be race condition on another effect I was listening on when using withLatestFrom operator so I do was change the of type to GetInitDataSuccess (`CommonActionsType.GetInitDataSuccess` action was fired before `GetUserSuccess`)

```
ofType(CommonActionsType.GetInitDataSuccess)
withLatestFrom(
            this.commonStore.pipe(select(selectUserData))
        ),
        mergeMap(([_, user]) => { 
              console.log(user);
```