# NGRX Action that depends on other observable(selector) values

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I've got a situation where I have 2 separate data sources that I need to fetch data from.  One data source depends on 2 values that come from other values in the store.

In the code sample below, I need to fetch a list of "banks" and render them.  Then at some point in the future, I need to "login" and fetch a list of "balances" for those banks.

I'm having trouble with the dependency part.  I can subscribe to the observables manually and it works, but I don't think it's the right way.  I suspect the right way is some combination of rxjs operators and selectors.  I'd appreciate some direction.

Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { getBalancesAction, getBanksAction, loginAction } from './store/app.actions';
import { selectBalances, selectBanks, selectLogin } from './store/app.selectors';
import { IAppState } from './store/app.state';
import * as _ from 'lodash';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit
{

    // Desired behavior
    // Banks render right off the bat.
    // CLicking login

    public banks$ = this.store.select(selectBanks);
    public login$ = this.store.select(selectLogin);
    public balances$ = this.store.select(selectBalances);

    constructor(private store: Store<IAppState>)
    {

    }

    ngOnInit()
    {
        this.store.dispatch(getBanksAction());

        // You can view the list of banks without being logged in
        // I need to call this.store.dispatch(getBalances(banks$, login$))
        // but only after I have a login and the list of banks.
        // I could subscribe, but that doesn't seem to be in the spirit of ngrx and rxjs.
        this.banks$.subscribe(banks =>
        {
            if (banks)
            {
                this.login$.subscribe(login =>
                {
                    if (login)
                    {
                        // getting balances requires the accountid and a list of banks.  These come from observables of their own.
                        this.store.dispatch(getBalancesAction({ accountId: login, banks: _.map(banks, b => b.id) }))
                    }
                })
            }
        });


    }

    public login(): void
    {
        this.store.dispatch(loginAction({ userName: 'justme' }));
    }
}
```

Actions

```
import { createAction, props } from "@ngrx/store";
import { IBalance, IBank } from "./app.state";

export enum BankActions
{
    GET_BANKS = "GET_BANKS",
    GET_BANKS_SUCCESS = "GET_BANKS_SUCCESS",
    GET_BALANCES = "GET_BALANCES",
    GET_BALANCE_SUCCESS = "GET_BALANCES_SUCCESS",
    LOGIN = "LOGIN",
    LOGIN_SUCCESS = "LOGIN_SUCCESS"
}

export const getBanksAction = createAction(
    BankActions.GET_BANKS
);

export const getBanksSuccessAction = createAction(BankActions.GET_BANKS_SUCCESS, props<{ banks: IBank[] }>());


export const getBalancesAction = createAction(
    BankActions.GET_BALANCES,
    props<{ accountId: string, banks: string[] }>()
);

export const getBalancesSuccessAction = createAction(BankActions.GET_BALANCE_SUCCESS, props<{ balances: IBalance[] }>());

export const loginAction = createAction(
    BankActions.LOGIN,
    props<{userName: string}>()
)

export const loginSuccessAction= createAction(
    BankActions.LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    props<{accountId: string}>()
)
```

effects

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Actions, createEffect, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { defer, forkJoin, from, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, mergeMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { BanksService } from '../banks.service';
import { BankActions, getBalancesSuccessAction, getBanksSuccessAction, loginSuccessAction } from './app.actions';

@Injectable()
export class BankEffects
{
    constructor(private actions$: Actions, private banksService: BanksService) { }

    loadBalances$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(BankActions.GET_BALANCES),
        mergeMap((x:any) => this.banksService.getBalances(x.accountId, x.banks)
            .pipe(
                map(b => getBalancesSuccessAction({ balances: b }))
            ))
    )
    );

    loadBanks$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(BankActions.GET_BANKS),
        mergeMap(() => this.banksService.getBanks()
            .pipe(
                map(b => getBanksSuccessAction({ banks: b }))
            ))
    )
    );

    doLogin$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(BankActions.LOGIN),
        mergeMap((x) => this.banksService.login(x)
            .pipe(
                map(b => loginSuccessAction({ accountId: b }))
            ))
    )
    );
}
```

Reducers

```
import { createReducer, on } from "@ngrx/store";
import { getBalancesSuccessAction, loginSuccessAction, getBanksSuccessAction } from "./app.actions";
import { IAppState, initialState } from "./app.state";

export const appReducer = createReducer(
    initialState,
    on(getBalancesSuccessAction, (state: IAppState, { balances }) => ({ ...state, balances: balances })),
    on(loginSuccessAction, (state: IAppState, { accountId }) => ({ ...state, accountId: accountId })),
    on(getBanksSuccessAction, (state: IAppState, { banks }) =>
    {
        return ({ ...state, banks: banks });
    }));
```

Selectors

```
import { createSelector } from "@ngrx/store";
import { IAppState } from "./app.state";

export const selectFeature = (state: any) => state.app;

export const selectLogin = createSelector(
    selectFeature,
    (state: IAppState) => state.accountId
);

export const selectBanks = createSelector(
    selectFeature,
    (state: IAppState) =>
    {
        return state.banks;
    }
);

export const selectBalances = createSelector(
    selectFeature,
    (state: IAppState) => state.balances
);
```

State

```
export interface IBank
{
    id: string;
    name: string;
}

export interface IBalance{
    bankId: string,
    value: number;
    internalAccountNumber: string
}

export interface IAppState
{
    banks: IBank[],
    accountId: string | null,
    balances: IBalance[]
}

export const initialState: IAppState = {
    banks: [],
    accountId: null,
    balances: []
};
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Your `ngOnInit` should only dispatch `BankActions.GET_BANKS`. It should not contain any `subscribe`s
2. Use `async` pipe in template to subscribe to `banks$` and `balances$`
3. `loadBalances$` should be triggered by `BankActions.LOGIN_SUCCESS`, you can get the account ID and banks list from the store within the effect using `withLatestFrom` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/60287236/1188074)
4. Remove `BankActions.GET_BALANCES`
5. Remove `login$` from your component

**References**

Chaining Effects

- Refer to this article by @timdeschryver, one of the core devs for ngrx: https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/start-using-ngrx-effects-for-this#prefetch-data
- Also recommend Mike Ryans talk on ['Good Action Hygiene'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JmnsEvoy-gY&t=303s) where he mentions 'Reducers and Effects should be the decision makers'.

Manual subscribes

- tweet by Ben Lesh (RxjS core dev) - scroll up:
  https://twitter.com/BenLesh/status/1090284770464911366

Comment: Making effects trigger on a success actions is usually bad practice. It creates a prescriptive and hidden chain of events. I would not recomend chaining event in particular for the OP's question. It looks like the `getBalancesAction` action should only triggered once (or maybe when their user refreshes the page but that's for another question).

Comment: So, if chaining success actions is bad and manually subscribing is bad, then what IS the answer.  Login can be triggered multiple times, thus get Balances would be triggered again.

Comment: Added references above plus mention `async` pipe explicitly. Re `getBalances` - do you want it to trigger only once regardless of number of logins?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest), as it yields all Observable's values

Also, you don't need loadash for the `map` function.

```js
combineLatest([this.banks$, this.login$])
    .pipe(
      // to prevent unwanted many yields on a short while
      debouncTime(50),
      // only yields when there are banks and the accountId is filled in.
      filter(([banks, accountId]) => banks?.length > 0 && accountId) 
    )
    .subscribe(([banks, accountId]) =>
      this.store.dispatch(getBalancesAction({ accountId, banks: banks.map(b => b.id) }))
    );
```

Comment: Manually subscribing is an ngrx anti-pattern as is passing info back in which already exists in the store - a component is not the place for all this logic.

Comment: @wlf it would be naive to recommend a full refactor of component subscriptions and related effects. The OP's source snippet likely suppressed a lot of the real code.  This answer is a minimal code change the OP could do to simplify their subscriptions without any other modifications

Comment: Relevant comment added to the other answer.