# RxJs withLatestFrom does not seem to emit if an observable emits late

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx-store

I have an NgRx effect where I need to get a couple of values from the store to then use in a service call.

These values may arrive late, so I want to wait for these to become available, as I use a `filter`.

I have the code below. Note I surround the `combineLatest` with a `withLatestFrom` as I could not find how else to get more than one values for the store (using a single `withLatestFrom`)

The code is as follows:

```
public loadData$ = createEffect(() =>
 this.actions$
  .pipe(
    ofType(appActions.viewOpened),
    tap(() => this.logger.info('loadData$')),
    
    withLatestFrom(
      combineLatest([
        this.store$.select(fromApp.getToken).pipe(filter(x => !!x)),
        this.store$.select(fromApp.getAuthorizationInfo).pipe(filter(x => !!x))
      ])),
        
    switchMap(([_, [token, authInfo]]) => {
      tap(() => this.logger.info(`loadData$ Got  ${token}`));
      const obs = from(this.getData(token, authInfo.userName));
      return obs;
    })
  ), { dispatch: false });

  
  private async getData: Promise<void> {
     ....
     // dispatches action(s)
  }
```

I am finding that if one of the `store$.select` does not have a value when the effect is first called, the `switchMap` is never entered, even once the two store values become available.

If both value ARE available, or I remove the `filter`, the `switchMap` is then entered.

My question is, why does the above occur, ie I am assuming the `withLatestFrom` is preventing the `switchMap` being called/

And also, if the above is incorrect usage,  how I should be getting these store values?

### Update 1

I have just found this is not working for an even simpler case even if I just want one store value. Eg even the below never enters the switch map:

```
 public loadData$ = createEffect(() =>
 this.actions$
  .pipe(
    ofType(appActions.viewOpened),
    tap(() => this.logger.info('loadData$')),
    
    withLatestFrom(this.store$.select(fromApp.getToken).pipe(filter(x => !!x)),
        
    switchMap(([_, token]) => {
      tap(() => this.logger.info(`loadData$ Got  ${token}`));
      const obs = from(this.getData(token));
      return obs;
    })
  ), { dispatch: false });
```

Comment: A feedback. It makes me wonder the following, you are dispatching an action, that will trigger an effect, this action `viewOpened` doesn't have any data on it, so you are force to grab something from the store with `withLatestFrom`, and in your `switchMap`, you even have  `_`... which is not going to be used... it's a waste... Why not grab whatever you need from the store, and then dispatch the action with a payload, so when you reach the `effect`, you just do your typical `http` call...

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you share what's going on within `getData`, something in there probably is wrong. Another thing, what is the last line of code `{dispatch: false}`?...

Comment: I could try and grab some data in the component that dispatches the viewOpened, but preferred the component to be as clean as possible and just dispatch "events", and then react to these however (some of which need some data, I have more than one effect that may listen to certain actions). `getData` call an existing method (not mine), that for better or worse is promise based. dispatch: false is as I dispatch actions in the getData from service call(s)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use withLatestFrom with a selector in ngrx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60282687/how-to-use-withlatestfrom-with-a-selector-in-ngrx)