# How to give the actions payload inside of an ngrx effect to the WiithLatestFrom() to grab a value from the state

Tags: angular, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

Hi i have the following effect but cant pass my actions payload to `getMainCareuserMessagesConversationAppointmentsShift(?)`

```
caregiverAcceptFetch = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions.pipe(
      ofType(rdxMainCareuserMessagesConversationCaregiverAcceptFetch),
      withLatestFrom(this.store.select(getTokenToken), this.store.select(getMainCareuserMessagesConversationAppointmentsShift(?how to use the current actions payload?))),
      switchMap(ac => aschax.post(`/payment-request/${ac[0].payload?.to}/${ac[0].payload!.appId}/${ac[0].payload?.cmId}`, null, {
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ac[1]
        }
      }).then(res => {
        let aschac: IAschacDispatch<IMainCareuserMessagesConversationCaregiverAcceptFetchSuccess> = {
          type: RDX_MAIN_CAREUSER_MESSAGES_CONVERSATION_CAREGIVER_ACCEPT_FETCH_SUCCESS,
          payload: {
            index: ac[0].payload?.index!,
            appid: ac[0].payload?.appId!,
            to: ac[0].payload?.to!
          }
        };
        return aschac;
      }).catch((err: AxiosError) => {
        let aschac: IAschacDispatch<IMainCareuserMessagesConversationCaregiverAcceptFetchError> = {
          type: RDX_MAIN_CAREUSER_MESSAGES_CONVERSATION_CAREGIVER_ACCEPT_FETCH_ERROR,
          payload: {
            error: err.response?.data,
            index: ac[0].payload?.index,
            appid: ac[0].payload?.appId!
          }
        }
        return aschac;
      }))
    );
  })
```

how could we pass the payload of the action inside of the second selector inside of our effect? `getMainCareuserMessagesConversationAppointmentsShift(?)`
could we do something like
`withLatestFrom(ac => [this.store.select(getTokenToken), this.store.select(getMainCareuserMessagesConversationAppointmentsShift(ac.payload?.index!)])`

Comment: Posted answer below is correct, linking this post as related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60282687/how-to-use-withlatestfrom-with-a-selector-in-ngrx/60287236

Answer (score 1):

You should use [concatLatestFrom](https://ngrx.io/guide/effects/operators#concatlatestfrom), it receives a function and you can get the action payload like a param

```
 concatLatestFrom(({actionPayload}) => this.store.select(getTokenToken), this.store.select(getMainCareuserMessagesConversationAppointmentsShift(actionPayload))),
```