# ngrx effect wait until response received from another state other than initial value

Tags: angular, ngrx, effect

In my angular 10 application, I am having below NgRx effect:

```typescript
loadValues$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(myActions.myActionTypes.LoadData),
    map((action: myActions.loadData) => action.payload),
    withLatestFrom(this._store.pipe(select(fromOtherState.getBioData))),
    switchMap(([action, profile]) => {
      return this.service
        .getDataValues(action["candidateID"], action["hasEnrolled"], profile)
        .pipe(
          map((data) => new myActions.LoadSuccess(data)),
          catchError((err) => of(new myActions.LoadFailed(err)))
        );
    })
  )
);
```

Here, I want to get value from "`fromOtherState.getBioData`" where initially it will have null value but later stage another action will fire and will populate this state. So, basically, I want to wait until it has other than a null value, and once it has desired value I want to go ahead and fire success action.

Please note that "`fromOtherState.getBioData`" has an associated action that will fire parallel when I am firing the above action, as of now it always gives me the profile as null.

Please note that I tried using `filter` as below: but with no luck:

```typescript
loadValues$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(myActions.myActionTypes.LoadData),
    map((action: myActions.loadData) => action.payload),
    withLatestFrom(this._store.pipe(select(fromOtherState.getBioData))),
    filter(([action, profile]) => {
      return profile != null; // here I want to wait until it has value other than null
    }),
    switchMap(([action, profile]) => {
      return this.service
        .getDataValues(action["candidateID"], action["hasEnrolled"], profile)
        .pipe(
          map((data) => new myActions.LoadSuccess(data)),
          catchError((err) => of(new myActions.LoadFailed(err)))
        );
    })
  )
);
```

Comment: Ngrx have a concatLatestFrom operator. For context see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60282687

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move your selector from `withLatestFrom` call to the `concatMap` and try filter it there. This way the rest of the effect should wait until the `getBioData` has some value. That's the sad part about the `withLatestFrom` operator, it doesn't care, it just provides.

```typescript
loadValues$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(myActions.myActionTypes.LoadData),
    map((action: myActions.loadData) => action.payload),
    concatMap((action) =>
      this_store.select(fromOtherState.getBioData).pipe(
        filter(profile => !!profile),
        map((profile) => ({action, profile}))
      )
    )
    switchMap(({action, profile}) => {
      return this.service
        .getDataValues(action["candidateID"], action["hasEnrolled"], profile)
        .pipe(
          map((data) => new myActions.LoadSuccess(data)),
          catchError((err) => of(new myActions.LoadFailed(err)))
        );
    })
  )
);
```

It's bit difficult for me to test it, but I have a feeling this approach might work.

Comment: Let me try and let you know, thanks @mat.hudak

Comment: this has worked, with little modification, thanks a lot @mat.hudak, I have modified your answer